# session.setPreferredInput in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, input, avaudiosession, nserror

I am trying to set the preferred input to my AVAudioEngine. I have the following code:

```
var iphoneInput: AVAudioSessionPortDescription = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().availableInputs[0] as! AVAudioSessionPortDescription

var error: NSError?

session.setPreferredInput(inPort: iphoneInput, error: error)
```

but Xcode keeps giving me errors for the last line stating taht it cannot invoke setPreferredinput with an arguement list of type '(AVAudioSessionPortDescription, NSError?)'

I am assuming it wants a NSErrorPointer for the error but I do not know how to create one in swift. Is this my problem and if so how do I create one? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `&` character before the variable to make it a pointer:

```
var myError: NSError?
session.setPreferredInput(iphoneInput, error: &myError)
if myError == nil {
    // do stuff
}
```

*Note: in Swift you don't have to use the method's first parameter's name.*

Comment: This works! I was just going to leave it as nil but this is the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for swift 3 does not work... you have to do (translated from ADC: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1799/_index.html
)

```
private func setupSession(){


let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

// setup session:
do {
    try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
    try session.setActive(true)
}
catch _{

}

// https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1799/_index.html

// let portDescr = AVAudioSessionPortDescription()

// headers:
// AVAudioSessionPortLineIn: String // Line level input on a dock connector
// AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic: String // Built-in microphone on an iOS device
// AVAudioSessionPortHeadsetMic: String // Microphone on a wired headset.  Headset refers to an accessory that has headphone outputs paired with a microphone.

// You cannot set directly..
// portDescr.portType = AVAudioSessionPortLineIn

guard let availableInputs = session.availableInputs else {
    return
}


var mic : AVAudioSessionPortDescription? = nil
for input in availableInputs {      
    if input.portType == AVAudioSessionPortBuiltInMic{
        mic = input
    }
}

guard mic != nil else{
    return
}

do {
    try session.setPreferredInput(mic)
}catch _ {
    print("cannot set mic ")
}
```

}